# If the ring $M_n(D)$ is a $k$-algebra, is $D$ a $k$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, let $D$ be a division ring.  Assume the matrix ring $A = M_n(D)$ is endowed with *some* $k$-algebra structure compatible with its ring structure (namely, for all $\lambda \in k$ and for all $M, N \in A$, $\lambda(MN) = (\lambda M)N = M(\lambda N$)).  We are *not* assuming a priori that there is an embedding of rings $k \to D \subset A$.

> Is it possible to show that such an embedding exists and, moreover, the resulting algebra structure on $D$ is naturally the restriction of the algebra structure on $A$?  Namely, if $(1, 1, \dots, 1) \in A$ is the identity matrix, then for all $\lambda \in k$, $$ \lambda \cdot (1, 1, \dots, 1) = (\lambda \cdot 1, \lambda \cdot 1, \dots, \lambda \cdot 1). $$

I want to use this fact on a qualifying exam.  It may be necessary to assume $k$ is algebraically closed?

I have tried proving this "directly", but have made embarrassingly little progress.  Thanks.

Comment: By algebra structure, do you mean a map $k\rightarrow Z(M_n(D))$ ? In other words, do you want that $\lambda(MN)=(\lambda M)N=M(\lambda N)$ for $\lambda\in k$ and $M,N\in M_n(D)$ ? In that case, since $Z(M_n(D))=Z(D)$, your question has a positive answer.

Comment: This is precisely what I mean, and I edited the question accordingly.  When viewed in that light, and using the fact you just mentioned, the result is indeed immediate.  Cool!  And thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A $k$-algebra structure on $A$ can simply be seen as a ring homomorphism $k\rightarrow Z(A)$ into the center of $A$.

Thus if you have a $k$-algebra structure on $M_n(D)$, you have a morphism $k\rightarrow Z(M_n(D))$. But $Z(M_n(D))=Z(D)$ consists of matrices of the form $d I_n$ for $d\in Z(D)$. See [here](https://mathtuition88.com/2016/01/16/center-of-matrix-algebra-matrix-ring-is-scalar-matrices/) for instance for a proof of this fact.

Thus, the $k$-algebra structure on $M_n(D)$ just comes from a $k$-algebra structure on $D$.